# Renaming files with atom editor in git controlled directories on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, atom-editor

```
cd ~/tmp
mkdir a b
touch a/foo b/foo
cd b
git init
```

Now open `atom` in each of the directories, try renaming `foo` to `bar`. In directory `a` it works as expected, in `b` you get error message *Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined'*. The file still gets renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[atom/github/issue  964](https://github.com/atom/github/issues/964) was already mentioning this error (file rename in a Git repo) in 2017.

Recently, it refers to [issue 22720](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/22720#) which says the fix would be in Atom 1.59. (1.59 is [still in beta](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases))

[Issue 22542](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/22542) also refers to [PR 22543](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/22543). It includes the current (2021) stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined
    at /usr/lib/atom/node_modules/git-diff/lib/git-diff-view.js:131:45
```

Comment: `1.60` still has the issue...